# Poco Websocket cant'r read large data

Tags: c++, websocket, poco-libraries

I use *Net::SocketReactor* on proccess connection. When data input into socket called something like the following code:

```
int WebSocketWrapper::DoRecieve(void *buf) {    
    try{
       int flags;
       const auto size = m_sock.availabel();
       const auto ret = m_sock.receiveFrame(buf, size, flags);
       if (size != ret){
           logger.warrning('Read less than available');
       }
       return ret;
   }
   catch (WebSocketException& exc){
       logger.log(exc);
       switch (exc.code()){
          case pnet::WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION:
             logger.debug("unsuported version");
             break;
              // fallthrough
          case pnet::WebSocket::WS_ERR_NO_HANDSHAKE:
          case pnet::WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_NO_VERSION:
          case pnet::WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_NO_KEY:
             logger.debug("Bad request");
             break;
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

It's good working when data size is less than 1400 bytes. TCP packs not fragmented. But when I try send data over 1400 bytes I have WebSocketException: "Insufficient buffer for payload size". I'm explore source code *Poco::Net::Websocket* and he found conflict. When call *Websocket::readFrame* analyzes the size of the frame a header, but I have only part of the frame. I can request that return *StreamSocket::availabel*.

How read large data from websocket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets operate in frames and you will always receive a frame or nothing. With that said, don't bother figuring out the amount of available data (you're probably hitting the ethernet 1500 byte MTU) but provide storage to accommodate the largest frame you expect to receive and call [receiveFrame()](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.6.1/Net/include/Poco/Net/WebSocket.h#L206). If the messages are fragmented between multiple frames, you'll have to deal with that at the application level. See [documentation](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.WebSocket.html#25042):

> Receives a frame from the socket and stores it
> in buffer. Up to length bytes are received. If
> the frame's payload is larger, a WebSocketException
> is thrown and the WebSocket connection must be
> terminated.

The upcoming 1.7 release will have [receiveFrame()](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/include/Poco/Net/WebSocket.h#L225) that resizes the buffer automatically to accomodate the frame.

To understand fragmented messages, see [Receiving Data](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-6.2) in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). While WebSockets are conceived as messaging protocol, some musings on whether they are really messaging or streaming can be found [here](http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2011/07/websockets-is-a-stream-not-a-message-based-protocol.html).

Also, the code you posted does not compile and the idea of writing an unknown number of bytes in a buffer of unknown size seems hazardous, to put it mildly.

Comment: You are right!  Pointer as paramater is bad idea. I have tried to simplify the code.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that we should ignore the result StreamSocket::availabel (), and use int  WebSocket::receiveFrame(Poco::Buffer<char>& buffer, int& flags)?

Comment: Yes, you understand it right. However, the version with `Poco::Buffer` is not released yet; so, unless you are using github development code, you should use the version with [fixed buffer](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.6.1/Net/src/WebSocket.cpp#L109) and make sure you provide enough room for the frame you are expecting.